# how to find particular Employee total amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an employee table. This table has three columns: `CustomerName`, `Role`, and `Salary`. In the `CustomerName` column User1 appears many times but I only want one row with the total salary of User1. Below I pasted some sample data for reference.

```
+--------------+------------+--------+
| CustomerName |    Role    | Salary |
+--------------+------------+--------+
| User1        | Design     |    100 |
| User2        | Developer  |    100 |
| User1        | Design     |    100 |
| User3        | Programmer |    100 |
| User1        | Design     |    100 |
+--------------+------------+--------+
```

Output should be like:

```
+--------------+------------+----------+
| CustomerName |     Role   |  Salary  |
+--------------+------------+----------+
| user1        | Design     |      300 |
| user2        | Developer  |      100 |
| user3        | Programmer |      100 |
+--------------+------------+----------+
```

I want the total amount of User1's salary. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `SUM` will do the trick. But why does user1 have multiple salaries to start with?

Comment: sorry based on  month wise .i put it here sample data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use aggregation with group by

```
select customername,role, sum(salary) as salary
from tablename
group by customername, role
```

Answer (score 2):

For user1

`select customername,role,sum(salary) from yourtable where customername='user1' group by customername,role`

Comment: why you put the where clause ? It's not required

Comment: Thanks @fa06.. I've read this `i am trying to achieve i want totally amount of user1 salary ?`